# Ok to use my free domain which I get from Firebase for package name for the android app when publishing in plays store

Tags: android, google-play, package-name

I have hosted my website in Firebase and I'm using `[myappname].web.app` free domain. I have android app associated with it and willing to publish it on google play-store. Is it ok to use `app.web.[myappname]` as the package name for it. Are there any legal issues since I'm not owning the web.app domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's okay. The package name of an Android app can be anything you want, as long as it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yeah. There is no issue with the uniqueness. But my problem is will there any legal issues ?

Comment: No there won't be.